# UITableView header and footer text doesn't get resized after dynamic text size change

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic-text

Is this a bug? I noticed that after a `UITableView` has been loaded, if I go to the system settings and change the dynamic text size, the headers/footers of the table view don't change to the new text size.

Everything else updates fine (i.e. the label text sizes inside the cells). Calling `reloadData` on the table view doesn't fix the issue. The only time the header/footer text sizes are correct is when the table view is first loaded.

Btw, I am not using custom views for the table view headers/footers. I'm just setting the text using the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` methods of `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: What headed and footer views are you using then?

Comment: I'm just setting the text using the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` methods of `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: You really need to add those details to the question.msection header is very different to header...